# Why does time.sleep pause tkinter window before it opens

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm developing a program for a stadium and `time.sleep()` pauses the program before the window opens instead of when I want it to. What is the explanation for this behavior?

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time
import random
root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Navigating To Seat")
label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

rand = random.randint(6, 16)

while rand != 0:
    label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Foward:  " + str(rand) + "m")
    label2.pack()
    rand = rand - 1
    time.sleep(1)
    label2.pack_forget()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you try putting your question's title into a Google search?

Comment: What _wouldn't_ it pause the program? That's exactly what `sleep` is for. If you don't want it to do that, why are you calling it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) does is suspend the execution of your program. If you do that 6-16 times, for 1 second each time, before ever calling `mainloop()`, you're asking it to wait for 6-16 seconds before starting up your GUI.

You probably don't understand how event loop programming works. Reading through some Tkinter tutorials should get the idea across nicely. If you want a less Tkinter-focused explanation and more information about the details of what's happening and the different ways to get around it, see [Why your GUI app freezes](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html).

At any rate, I think I can guess what you want to do, even though it isn't clear from your question: You want to start the GUI up, and then, every second, replace the `Label`. To do that, you have to wait *while the GUI is running*, not before it starts.

But you can't just call `sleep` while the GUI is running, either. The GUI can't run while your program is asleep (again, that's what `sleep` means).

The easiest way out of this is to turn your loop into a sequence of function calls, each of which schedules the next one to run a second later, using the [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method. For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random
root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Navigating To Seat")
label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

rand = random.randint(6, 16)
label2 = None

def add_label():
    global rand
    global label2
    if not rand:
        root.quit()
    if label2:
        label2.pack_forget()
    label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Foward:  " + str(rand) + "m")
    label2.pack()
    rand = rand - 1
    root.after(1000, add_label)

add_label()
root.mainloop()
```

When you first call `add_label()`, it creates the initial label, asks `Tkinter` to call `add_label()` again in 1000 milliseconds, and returns. So, a second after you start the loop, it gets called again, which creates the next label and asks `Tkinter` to call it again a second later. This keeps going until you decrement `rand` all the way to `0`, at which point you call `quit` instead of `after`, which ends the main loop, which ends the program.

There are other things you probably want to fix about this program. For example, instead of destroying and creating a new Widget label each time, you can just change its text—or, maybe even more simply, make `rand` an [`IntVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) connected to the label, so just updating `rand` automatically changes the text. Also, for anything less trivial than this program, you'd probably want to replace the global variables with something cleaner—most Tkinter tutorials show you how to use a `Frame` subclass by about the second or third example, which gives you a convenient place to organize both widgets and member variables like `rand`.

Comment: This is a very nice explanation, but it would be also nice if you mention the method `after_cancel`...

Comment: @Xenomorph: Where would you use `after_cancel` for this design? The `after` method doesn't trigger repeatedly, just once, so there's nothing to cancel here.

Comment: Just to mention it in contrast to the `after` method, I did not say it was needed for the solution.. maybe I am just mad.

Comment: @Xenomorph: I don't think it's really relevant here, and it's already mentioned in the `after` docs I linked to (as well as being the next section anyway). Can you think of a way to offer an explanation that would give the OP a clue as to what it's useful for without coming up with a more complicated example (e.g., adding a "stop" button)?