# Python display variable with tkinter inside a method

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, tkinter

The program I just wrote is my playground for finding out how Tkinter works.
My question is how do I display my variable "timelabel" as a Label.

I allready made a label called timerefresher yet it doesnt show up.

I am aware that the DigitalClock class isn't written efficiently. I am new to this ;).

```
def Clockupdate(time):
    timelabel = time
    timerefresher = Label(root, textvariable=timelabel)
    timerefresher.pack()
    #print(timelabel) To test if variable made it this far.

class DigitalClock:
    def secondrefesher(self):
        newtime = ""
        while 1 == 1:
            oldtime = datetime.datetime.now()
            a = str(oldtime.hour)
            b = str(oldtime.minute)
            c = str(oldtime.second)
            curtime = (a+":"+b+':'+c)
            if curtime != newtime:
                newtime = curtime
                #print("made it here")
                Clockupdate(newtime)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.20)

DC = DigitalClock()

root = Tk()
mainlabel = Label(root, text="Hey this is working!")
Pressme = Button(root, text="Press me!", command=Presstoshowtextandpic, 
bg='red', fg='white')
Clock = Button(root, text="Clock?", command=DC.secondrefesher, bg='blue', 
fg='white')
Photo = PhotoImage(file="test.png")
ShowPhoto = Label(root, image=Photo)

mainlabel.pack()
Pressme.pack()
Clock.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide your imports so we can see if you have everything imported that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so Here is what I would do with your code to accomplish what you are trying to do.

First lets make sure we have the correct imports.

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import time
```

I created this `doNothing()` function as a place holder for any commands I am not currently testing.

```
def doNothing():
    pass
```

Now the way you had your `Clockupdate(time):` function would cause the label to be added every time you click the clock button. so this is probably not what you want as it just keeps adding new labels instead of replacing the existing one. Take a look at this function. All I do in this is `.config()` the text to be the time argument from the function. Note you do not need to redefine the time to timelabel or anything of the sort, just use time as your varable.

```
def Clockupdate(time):
    timerefresher.config(text = time)
```

I don't know if you wanted to use a class for a specific reason but I think you should just use a function here. Also try to keep your quotes consistent. I know they are interchangeable but its good practice to keep them consistent.

```
def secondrefesher():
    newtime = ""
    oldtime = datetime.datetime.now()
    a = str(oldtime.hour)
    b = str(oldtime.minute)
    c = str(oldtime.second)
    curtime = (a + ":" + b + ":" + c)
    if curtime != newtime:
        newtime = curtime
        Clockupdate(newtime)
```

Note I always place commands at the end of any config of a button. It helps when managing code so you can just check the end of each line as you scroll through your code. I also changed the command for Pressme to doNothing so I could test the code. You didn't provide the code for Presstoshowtextandpic and would not be able to test the code with out that part. Remember when asking a question here to use [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

```
root = Tk()
mainlabel = Label(root, text="Hey this is working!")
Pressme = Button(root, text = "Press me!", bg = "red", fg = "white", command  = doNothing)
Clock = Button(root, text = "Clock?", bg = "blue", fg = "white", command = secondrefesher)
Photo = PhotoImage(file = "test.png")
ShowPhoto = Label(root, image = Photo)
```

Here I created the time label just once and then you can call the update function all you want to change the text to current time.

```
timerefresher = Label(root, text = "")
timerefresher.pack()

mainlabel.pack()
Pressme.pack()
Clock.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Here is what I think the completed code should look like for you.

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import time

def Clockupdate(time):
    timerefresher.config(text = time)

def secondrefesher():
    newtime = ""
    oldtime = datetime.datetime.now()
    a = str(oldtime.hour)
    b = str(oldtime.minute)
    c = str(oldtime.second)
    curtime = (a + ":" + b + ":" + c)
    if curtime != newtime:
        newtime = curtime
        Clockupdate(newtime)

root = Tk()
mainlabel = Label(root, text = "Hey this is working!")
Pressme = Button(root, text = "Press me!", bg = "red", fg = "white", command  = Presstoshowtextandpic)
Clock = Button(root, text = "Clock?", bg = "blue", fg = "white", command = secondrefesher)
Photo = PhotoImage(file = "test.png")
ShowPhoto = Label(root, image = Photo)

timerefresher = Label(root, text = "")
timerefresher.pack()

mainlabel.pack()
Pressme.pack()
Clock.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Edit:

In case you are trying to create a clock that is always active and does not require you to click the button you can use `.after()`.

Take a look at this example.

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import time

root = Tk()
mainlabel = Label(root, text = "Hey this is working!")
Photo = PhotoImage(file = "test.png")

timerefresher = Label(root, text = "")
timerefresher.pack()

status_time = ""
def tick():
    global status_time
    time2 = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    if time2 != status_time:
        status_time = time2
        timerefresher.config(text = time2)
    timerefresher.after(200, tick)
tick()

mainlabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Very nice! you fixed all the problems I had. Especially the `.after()` is very useful! You suggest using `.after()` instead of `time.sleep() for any pause in tinker?`

Comment: @Anton: `.sleep()` in tkinter will pause the entire program and not just wait to perform the next operation, where `.after()` will count the ticks and then perform a task. take a look at this post for a more detailed [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284270/why-does-time-sleep-pause-tkinter-window-before-it-opens) of the `sleep` problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should have written an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that one can test your code, especially that things are missing (such as `Presstoshowtextandpic()`).

When reading the rest of your code, I think you need to read about [variable classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) and modify Clockupdate() as follows:

```
def Clockupdate(time):
    timelabel = StringVar() # modified
    timelabel.set(time) # added
    timerefresher = Label(root, textvariable=timelabel.get()) #modified
    timerefresher.pack()
```

P.S. You should write [`clock_update()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) instead of `Clockupdate()`

Comment: I changed the things you suggested, the variable propably has been assigned correctly, but I think the problem is in the    timerefresher.pack line. I have written a MCVE. for some reason it just doesnt update the screen.